# Using Google Maps KML Importing Utility on top of a custom tile

Tags: android, google-maps, kml, tile

I need to add a customTile and a kmlLayer to a googleMap.
What I´m looking for is a way of setting the z-index of the kmlLayer, in order to see  my customTile and the kmlLayer on top of the tile. Currently the kmlLayer is under the tile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `kmlLayer` has no managed `Z-Index` property and seems it set by default to `0`, you can use workaround: set `Z-Index` to `-1` for your custom [`TileOverlay`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay#setZIndex(float)):

```
TileOverlay tileOverlay = mGoogleMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions()
            .tileProvider(tileProvider)
            .zIndex(-1));
```